# InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to load service data in ngfor through async pipe but i am facing an issue:
this is my component:

```
    <app-book-list *ngFor="let app of apps | async | serachBox:searchBooksByName | filterSearch:showTechBooks:showMgmBooks:showFictionBooks " 
  [bookdetails]="app"></app-book-list>
```

In this component apps is supposed to come from service.

In My component.ts file:

```
     public apps= [];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.ServerService.getBookDetails()
      .then((data)=>{
        this.apps = data;
      })
  }
```

And below is the promise:

getBookDetails(){

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
   return this.http.get('https://lib-http-ng.firebaseio.com/bookdetails.json')
        .toPromise()
        .then((res)=>{
            const data = Object.values(res.json());
            resolve(data[0])
        })

})
return promise;
```

}
I am getting an error related to async pipe.

1.

```
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Promise<any>'.
```

Comment: Your code uses several pipes. Which pipe causes the error? What value causes the error?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it should the be `| async`, shouldn't it ? "for pipe    'AsyncPipe'"

Comment: You are right. If you'd remove the other pipes you'd still get the same error. This would lead to https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve which is usually a good idea to do with code in a SO question.

Comment: why don't u use RxJS library ? it's sooooo much easier to handle async calls

Answer (score 0):

```
this.ServerService.getBookDetails()
  .then((data)=>{
    console.log(data);
    this.apps =  data;
  })
```

should be

```
this.apps = this.ServerService.getBookDetails()
```

or remove `| async`

Comment: If i remove async then i have to reload page for showing data. Data is coming in async way.

Comment: In this case there is probably something wrong in `this.ServerService.getBookDetails()`. What about the 2nd option?

Comment: What does "forces the same behavior" mean? If you do `this.apps = data`, then `apps` isn't a `Promise` or `Observable`, therefore `| async` is invalid. With `this.apps = this.ServerService.getBookDetails()` (updated the code, I had `this.data = ...` previously) you probably get a `Promise` (can't know for sure because I don't know the content of `getBookDetails()`.

Comment: edited the code. I am getting the data but i am not able to view data. Now i get the error,  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Promise<any>'.

Comment: If `apps` is a promise, you need to assign a promise, that's not what your code does. `this.apps = this.ServerService.getBookDetails()` assigns a promise

Comment: I dont want pipe to be promise. I changed it to array type, but now i get an error saying:  " InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: I can't make sense of your comments. If `apps` is not a `Promise`, then don't use `| async`. `| async` can't be used for values that are not `Promise` or `Observable`.

Comment: okay what i am trying to do is after login this service will be called and data will be shown. But with this.apps = this.ServerService.getBookDetails() i need to reload the page again. I do not get why i need to reload the page. I want it to be SPA

Comment: I see no reason in your code that could make it necessary to reload.

Comment: i the network tab in console data is coming but still i need to reload it. I dont know whats happenning

Comment: I don't know either. If you can reproduce in stackblitz.com I might be able to help, but the currently available information doesn't provide a hint.